# Custom Android URI

Tags: android, android-activity, uri, custom-url

I have read several custom URI posts here and attempted to create a working URI scheme. However, it is not working. Code below for XML:

```
<activity android:name="testhing.ResetPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_reset_password"
            android:parentActivityName="testthing.LoginActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="restthing.LoginActivity" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="TESTTHING" android:host="ForgottenPassword" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

If I attempt to navigate to 'TESTHING://ForgottenPassword' in the browser, it runs a google search but does not open the view. I have a link in an email that is 'TESTHING://ForgottenPassword?token=12345', but this link doesn't even show as clickable. It acts as if the custom URI scheme isn't registered. Is there something wrong in my syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I attempt to navigate to 'TESTHING://ForgottenPassword' in the browser, it runs a google search but does not open the view.

There are many browsers for Android. Some might attempt to use `PackageManager` to see if this random series of characters happens to be a `Uri` for an `ACTION_VIEW` activity when you enter it in the address bar. There is no requirement that a browser do this.

> I have a link in an email that is 'TESTHING://ForgottenPassword?token=12345', but this link doesn't even show as clickable.

There are many email clients for Android. Ideally, an email client, when seeing a link, will at least try the `ACTION_VIEW` operation with whatever the link claims to be linking to. Once again, there is no requirement that an email client do this.

> Is there something wrong in my syntax?

I would recommend going with all lowercase for your scheme and host. For example, your email client might be applying a regex that assumes a lowercase scheme, as that's the normal way that URI schemes are written.

On the whole, custom schemes have only one redeeming value on Android: they are less likely to collide with anything else and trigger a chooser. You are far more likely to have apps recognize your links if you use `http` as your scheme, going with the "this app handles these URLs" approach. Right now, though, that will trigger a chooser, where the user could choose a browser or your app. That's why in Android M, they are adding the ability to provide evidence on the server that you "own" the URL and that you want these links to drive straight to your app and bypass the chooser.

Comment: Currently, I can't change the scheme. It's part of some legacy code in an API that can't be altered right now, as it will affect an iOS version of the application.

Comment: @steventnorris: Then you'll have to settle for the fact that it will not work in some browsers, email clients, and other places where your URL shows up.

Comment: It works in none of them. However, on the iPhone it works perfectly.

Comment: Also, I change the scheme to match lower case testhing://forgottenpassword and it still won't pick up in the browser. It isn't registering the scheme.

Comment: @steventnorris: "It isn't registering the scheme" -- the test of whether your app is or is not "registering the scheme" is for you to create your own `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, with a `Uri` that should match your `<intent-filter>`, and see if it works with `startActivity()`. If you get an `ActivityNotFoundException`, there is a problem. If your activity launches, then your code is fine. However, short of you taking hostages, there is no way that you can force the rest of the world's app developers to necessarily start an `ACTION_VIEW` activity when they encounter your custom URL syntax.

Comment: Alright, so that worked. Does that mean that both Android's default browser and email client won't recognize custom URIs but iOS does? That seems like poor planning. Also, I've seen that some have had success with using a regular link (http://testhing/forgottenpassword) that redirected to the custom URI. In your opinion, would this option be a workaround?

Comment: @steventnorris: "Does that mean that both Android's default browser and email client won't recognize custom URIs" -- there are many "default browser and email client" apps for Android, as device manufacturers routinely ship their own. Google themselves have been steadily backpedaling away from the custom-scheme route, as I think the IETF yelled at them. However, even using `http` schemes will not necessarily work: Chrome (and Firefox) both assume that all `http` URLs refer to Web pages that they should load themselves. On the whole, URL-based links to activities have issues.

Comment: @steventnorris: "In your opinion, would this option be a workaround?" -- I have not tried that. One problem is in reliable user-agent sniffing: what happens if the URL is visited by a desktop browser, for example, where the custom scheme would not be usable? But, it's certainly worth experimenting with.

Comment: That seems like the most plausible solution at this point. The app is self-contained, so there really shouldn't be any functionality for the webpage beyond being opened on a mobile device. I need the app to open via a url sent in an email, so I can't exactly navigate away from that right now.

Comment: For the sake of it being here, the redirect did not work. Support for custom URI scheme is nerfed considerably. However, using http or the intent:// structure defined by android will work. This will not work from typing it into the mobile browser bar; however, clicking an http link for a registered scheme will prompt to open in either the browser or the app.